# Nifi ExecuteSql very slow with Oracle

Tags: apache-nifi

I am having a simple flow where i am using GenerateTableFetch to create pages of 2000 record and feed them to ExecuteSql. The ExecuteSql is taking too long to process Oracle 12c and Nifi version 1.7.1.

I redcued the Max wait time to 10seconds but it is not failing so looks like ExecuteSql is taking time to convert to avro. The table is having a million record.

I am using ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar. Is there any way to improve performance?

The simple flow is taking 2hr for million records.

Comment: is it taking 2 hr to get data using ExecuteSQL?.. keep query in `executesql` processor as **select * from <table_name> (no lock)** and let us know how much time it is taking to get a million records..
change the Max Wait time to **0 sec** because we don't know how much time it will take at most and im pretty sure if we keep **10sec** as max wait time it will fail **(we cannot pull million records in 10 sec from RDBMS)**

Comment: it is taking 2hr to fetch data taking input from GenerateTableFetch 2000 page size. The timeout error never comes but takes lot of time to output after conversion to avro.

Comment: Could you share your **GenerateTableFetch** processor configs and is your table have `index` on the columns that used for partition?

Comment: Database Type : Oracle 12+
Max wait time : 10 Sec (It never fails for connection timeout error)
Partition Size : 2500
Column for Value Partitiong : None

Table is indexed.

Comment: @SiddharthChaurasia, have you tried to export data through sqlplus for example? is it faster for million records?

Comment: yeah it took approx 15min for same table